# "-bash: twine: command not found" when attempting to upload to PyPi

Tags: python, bash, pip, pypi, twine

I am attempting to publish a package to PyPi using `twine`. Running `twine upload dist/*` in the project folder gives `-bash: twine: command not found`.

I am using Python 3.7.7 on MacOS Mojave. I have run `pip install twine` successfully, and running `pip3 install twine` tells me that `twine` is already installed.

I have seen other answers suggesting that I add the directory where `twine` is installed to the `$PATH` in my `~/.bash_profile`. Running `pip show -f twine` gives me:

```
Name: twine
Version: 3.1.1
Summary: Collection of utilities for publishing packages on PyPI
Home-page: https://twine.readthedocs.io/
Author: Donald Stufft and individual contributors
Author-email: donald@stufft.io
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/Username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: requests, importlib-metadata, tqdm, keyring, requests-toolbelt, setuptools, readme-renderer, pkginfo
Required-by: 
Files:
  ../../../bin/twine
```

followed by a list of files.

I have added `/Users/Username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/bin`, 
`/Users/Username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages`, and `/Users/Username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/bin` to the `$PATH`, as per various answers, and the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `/Users/Username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/bin` and `/Users/Username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/bin` to the `$PATH`, and that appears to have fixed the problem.